# What is the class and method where Envers is passing audit tables metadata to Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I would like to exclude Envers audit tables form Hibernate generate / validate phase, but they still need to be present in Evners context. I can't see a place where Envers is passing them to Hibernate.

Any ideas where could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to exclude the DDL scripts for the envers audit table while doing hibernate schema generation? If this is your question, then sadly you cannot (AFAIK). Envers picks up all entities that are marked auditable and creates their DDL queries.